# In python: filter out elements in a list of dicts where some property is underrepresented

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries

```
[   {'x': 1, 'cat': 1},
    {'x': 1, 'cat': 1},
    {'x': 1, 'cat': 2},
    {'x': 1, 'cat': 1},
    {'x': 1, 'cat': 2},
    {'x': 1, 'cat': 1},
    {'x': 1, 'cat': 2},
    {'x': 1, 'cat': 3}]
```

I need to filter out elements who's 'cat' value is present too few times
if I set the minimum number of instances to two, in the list above, the instance containing 'cat': 3 should be filtered out because 'cat':3 is present only once in the list, there are enough instances of 'cat': 1 and 'cat': 2

the output should be

```
[   {'x': 1, 'cat': 1},
    {'x': 1, 'cat': 1},
    {'x': 1, 'cat': 2},
    {'x': 1, 'cat': 1},
    {'x': 1, 'cat': 2},
    {'x': 1, 'cat': 1},
    {'x': 1, 'cat': 2}]
```

I don't care about the order, I need to keep original dictionaries

Comment: what is the criteria for deciding whether a category is underrepresented? If it's present only once? If it's present at most n times? It it's the least represented in the list?

Comment: the category should be present at least n times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to check the frequency of categories and build a set from the ones that are frequent enough:

```
import collections
source = [{'x': 1, 'cat': 1},
          {'x': 1, 'cat': 1},
          {'x': 1, 'cat': 2},
          {'x': 1, 'cat': 1},
          {'x': 1, 'cat': 2},
          {'x': 1, 'cat': 1},
          {'x': 1, 'cat': 2},
          {'x': 1, 'cat': 3}]
minimum_count = 2

category_counts = collections.Counter(item['cat'] for item in source)
# category_counts == {1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 1}

frequent_categories = {
    category for category, count in category_counts.items()
    if count > minimum_count
}
# frequent_categories == {1, 2}

result = [item for item in source if item['cat'] in frequent_categories]
```

Comment: this was my first attempt, wondering if existed some different approach

Comment: @JackNova is there anything in particular you don't like about this solution?

Comment: @JackNova no, I mean, there are different approaches, if you can tell me what you don't like in this one, I (or someone) can surely come up with one that fits your needs better.

Comment: @JackNove …or if you're really not interested in other answers anymore, would you mind marking this answer as accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
l = [ 

{'x': 1, 'cat': 1},

{'x': 1, 'cat': 1},

{'x': 1, 'cat': 2},

{'x': 1, 'cat': 1},

{'x': 1, 'cat': 2},

{'x': 1, 'cat': 1},

{'x': 1, 'cat': 2},

{'x': 1, 'cat': 3}

]

from collections import Counter

def select(l, times):

    counters = Counter(map(lambda x : x['cat'], l)).most_common(times)

    return filter(lambda item: item['cat']  in dict(counters) , l)

print select(l, 2)
```